# Error: 'IpageIndicator' directive or assembly reference missing? in xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have dowloaded code from github of *imageslider in xamarin* android from [Xamarin-Android-Image-Auto-Slider-and-OOM-Issue-Ha](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1038358/Xamarin-Android-Image-Auto-Slider-and-OOM-Issue-Ha), below is the file it shows error...

```
namespace autoImageSlider
{
    [Activity (Label = "AutoImageScroller")]    
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionMain }, Categories = new[] { "dk.ostebaronen.viewpagerindicator.droid.sample" })]
    public class AutoImageScroller : FragmentActivity
    {
        Button  btn;
        private List<int> itemData;
        private int imageValue;
        FragStateSupport _adapter;
        ViewPager _pager;
        protected IPageIndicator _indicator;
        bool Continue = false;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Create your application here
            itemData = new List<int> ();
            itemData.Add (Resource.Drawable.photo1);
            itemData.Add (Resource.Drawable.photo2);
            itemData.Add (Resource.Drawable.photo3);
            itemData.Add (Resource.Drawable.photo4);
            imageValue = 0;

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.simple_circle_viewpager);

            //Set up adapter with List of photo ID as item Data
            _adapter = new FragStateSupport(SupportFragmentManager,itemData);

            //Setup pager reference
            _pager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.pager);
            _pager.Adapter = _adapter;

            //Setup CirclePageIndicator Reference
            _indicator = FindViewById<CirclePageIndicator>(Resource.Id.indicator);
            _indicator.SetViewPager(_pager);

            btn = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);
            btn.Click += HandleClick;
            btn.Text = "Run Slider";
        }

        async void HandleClick (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Continue) {
                btn.Text = "Run Slider";
                Continue = false;
            } else {
                Continue = true;
                btn.Text = "Stop";
            }

            if (Continue) {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (o => RunSlowMethod ());
            }
        }

        public void RunSlowMethod()
        {
            while (Continue) {
                imageValue = imageValue + 1;
                if (imageValue > 3) {
                    imageValue = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine("Compute reset : t" + imageValue);
                }
                Thread.Sleep (2000);
                this.RunOnUiThread (() => _pager.SetCurrentItem (imageValue, true));
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDestroy ()
        {
            Continue = false;
            base.OnDestroy ();
        }
    }
}
```

It shows me error saying...

> The type or namespace name `IpageIndicator` Could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

In references folder it showing exclametory mark for `DK.Ostebaronen.Droid.ViewPagerIndicator.`

Please help me, what should be done here.I am new bee in xamarin android.